# Enter Private Key Passphrase for Git in While SSH'ing bash script

Tags: bash, git, ssh

Here's the code I have so far in an `<<EOF` while ssh'ing into a box

```
mkdir ~/.ssh/
rm ~/.ssh/config
touch ~/.ssh/config
echo 'Host *******' >> ~/.ssh/config
echo '   StrictHostKeyChecking no' >> ~/.ssh/config

cp ~/gittoken ~/.ssh/id_rsa
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa

cd /root
git clone ***********
expect "assword:"
send "$git_token_passphrase\r";
interact
```

The error I'm getting is

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I've sort of combined multiple different answers I've seen on SO that I thought might help my case.

**I can run all these commands when I'm manually running them on the box.** So my guess is that running them while ssh'ed through a script requires some extra step. Also, expect and send don't work on my system, but I figured I'd put them there anyway to show I'd tried them.

```
/bin/bash: line 105: expect: command not found
/bin/bash: line 106: send: command not found
/bin/bash: line 107: interact: command not found
```

Comment: You need to install expect.

Comment: @JoachimdeGroot It is installed now, but still getting `send` and `interact` command not founds

Comment: So I realize I have to do `/bin/expect` instead of `/bin/bash` but this `EOF` is the provisioner, so `expect` will not be installed by default. Seems like a catch 22..

Comment: Unless you have a way to avoid storing the passphrase in clear text, you might consider just removing it from the key so that you can dispense with this part of the script.

Comment: Actually, seeing as you are sending a remote script, I would set up `ssh-agent` on the *local* host, then enable agent forwarding so that the remote `git` can pick up the (unlocked) key over the `ssh` connection. No `expect` needed.

Comment: @chepner I have `Host ****
   StrictHostKeyChecking no
   AddKeysToAgent yes
   UseKeychain yes
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
` in my .ssh/config, still getting same error

Comment: If you are getting the same error, then you haven't removed the `expect` cruft from you script yet.

Answer (score 2):

You may use [`sshpass`](https://packages.debian.org/sshpass) to achieve this.

**But** since now *the security* of the whole setup rests not in the head of
whoever knows the password but *is only as strong as
the security in the script* or—if you're a bit
less slack—into some file holding the password, you might as well just
remove password protection from your SSH key by running

```
ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -p
```

and entering an empty password twice.

Comment: `ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -p`